# Android Studio won't let me change java compiler backwards, from java 8 to java 7

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I need to update my website at google app engine. Since I last uploaded it, java upgraded to java 8. Now, my sight fails, with the message: **failure in app engine**

[image: **failure in app engine**]

I think this means it is failing because app engine can't handle java 8. When I try to change from java 8 to java 7 in android studio, it won't let me. It says: refuses to use java 7

[image: refuses to use java 7]

and revert back to java 8.
I'm only doing all this because Google sent me a nasty message saying I need to include a security policy on my web site.

Comment: Have you looked an existing questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=please+choose+jdk+8+or+newer&oq=please+choose+jdk+8+o&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.3356j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes, for many hours of many days.

Comment: Update: I now believe the problem occurs because android studio updated from 1 to 2 since I worked on this program. Android Studio requires java 8. However, Google App Engine forbids java 8. If this is true, it is hard to believe, and a classic example of the left hand not knowing what the right hand is doing. I'll try downloading an old copy of Android studio 1, to see if that fixes the problem (tomorrow, my head hurts today).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, and it is shocking: almost unbelievable. Android Studio 2.x forbids using Java 7 (Java 8 is required). The Google App Engine forbids using Java 8 (Java 7 is required). This means you cannot use the current version of Android Studio to develop Google App Engine Apps! Old App Engine apps or web sites developed with Android Studio 1.x will fail if you try to redeploy them to to the App Engine using your upgraded Android Studio 2.x. To solve the problem, I reinstalled an old version of android studio 1.5, following the instructions at http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-2. The uploaded web site works fine, now.